# Javascript get CSS style for ID

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I would like to be able to get the style from a CSS element which is not used on the webpage. For example, this is the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#custom{
background-color: #000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>Hello world</p>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see the ID 'custom' has a value but is not used within the document. I would like to get all the values for 'custom' without using it in the page. The closest I have come is:

```
el = document.getElementById('custom');
var result;
var styleProp = 'background-color';
if(el.currentStyle){
    result = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
    }else if (window.getComputedStyle){
    result = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    }else{
    result = "unknown";
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are trying to reimplement CSS classes? Please tell us what you want the end result to be and we can help you get there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new element with given ID and append it to the document. Then just read the value and remove the element.

Example:

```
var result,
    el = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div")),
    styleProp = 'background-color',
    style;

el.id = 'custom';
style = el.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
result = style[styleProp] || "unknown";

// Remove the element
document.body.removeChild(el);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the answer was a very good one as it requires adding elements to the DOM which may disrupt what you are trying to do or create visual glitches.

Using document.styleSheets I think you can get a less invasive solution. (see [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript))

try something like:

```
var result;
var SS = document.styleSheets;
for(var i=0; i<SS.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<SS[i].cssRules.length; j++) {
        if(SS[i].cssRules[j].selectorText == "#custom") {
            result = SS[i].cssRules[j].style;
        }
    }
}
```

This should give you an object which will contain all of the styles as the keys. keep in mind you may need a little more complex algorithm if the style is redeclared within the stylesheets.