# Can Kinetic.js be made to use css values

Tags: javascript, css, kineticjs

I'm trying to use some kinetic.js elements on a page that also has normal formatting via css.  I would like Kinetic.js to use the same font styles the rest of the page uses.  What's the right way to get my kinetic objects to pull styles from my css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might do is extract your css rules into an object and apply them to KineticJs text.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004475/jquery-css-plugin-that-returns-computed-style-of-element-to-pseudo-clone-that-el?lq=1) offers a way to do that with jQuery.

Essentially, you could do something like:

```
var el = document.getElementById("someStyledElement");
var css = window.getComputedStyle(el);
var text = new Kinetic.Text({
  fontSize: css.fontSize,
  fontStyle: css.fontStyle,
  fontFamily: css.fontFamily,
  fill: css.color
});
```

Of course YMMV.  It's likely that you'd need to process the styles somewhat before passing them to KineticJS.

Comment: I was having a problem doing this because my script was loading before the DOM finished building.  We're using require.js and I was having a hard time working around this problem.  I ended up taking your suggestion along with the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311172/javascript-get-css-style-for-id